# Recovering files from a bad data DVD

Tags: dvd, data-recovery

I don't know if this was a bad burn or it was damaged in the sun or what. There are visible ripples on the disc that are not typical.

I'm running Linux, but I have access to Windows if need be. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to recover the data on this disc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just grabbing what I could with ddrescue. Thanks for the suggestions, guys.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [BadCopy Pro](http://www.jufsoft.com/badcopy/):

> BadCopy Pro is the leading data
>   recovery software for floppy disk, CD,
>   DVD, memory card, Zip disk, USB flash
>   drive and other storage media. BadCopy
>   Pro can effectively recover and rescue
>   corrupted or lost data from damaged,
>   unreadable, formatted or defective
>   disks. It works with Microsoft Windows
>   95/98/2000/NT/ME/XP/2003/Vista.

They offer it in trial so you can assess if it can read your media before you buy it.

Answer (score 0):

Free program here

http://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29

.